# Can't seem to return int value from Main to Player Class

Tags: java, android, class, variables, return

I have been trying to return an int value from my MainActivity to my player class to determine which direction he should move and which set of images from my sprite sheet should be used. I am only seeming to recieve 0 in my Player class. I know that my accelorometer code is working as I have tested this seperately however the int isnt passing from MainActivity to Player. All help is appreciated! Thank you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    //Accelerometer
    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer;

    private volatile int direction;

    private static int DIRECTION_STATIONARY = 0;
    private static int DIRECTION_DOWN = 1;
    private static int DIRECTION_LEFT = 2;
    private static int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 3;
    private static int DIRECTION_UP = 4;

    Player player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GameView gameView = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);

        //Accelerometer
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if (sensorEvent.values[0] < -1){
                direction = DIRECTION_UP;
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[0] > 1){
                direction = DIRECTION_DOWN;
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[1] < -1){
                direction = DIRECTION_LEFT;
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[1] > 1){
                direction = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
            }
            else{
                direction = DIRECTION_STATIONARY;
            }
            //Log.d("Player Update", "X:" +sensorEvent.values[0]+ " Y:" +sensorEvent.values[1]+ " Z:" +sensorEvent.values[2] + " Direction: " + direction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    public int getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }
}
```

**GameView.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import...

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Thread thread;

    Player player;


    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        player = new Player(context, this);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Update();
            DrawCanvas();
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        player.Update();
        player.UpdateAnim();
        Control();
    }

    private void DrawCanvas() {

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            canvas.drawBitmap(player.getSprite(), player.getSrc(), player.getDst(), null);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        } else {
            Log.d("Run", "Surface Invalid");
        }
    }

    private void Control() {
        try {
            thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import ...

public class Player {

    private Bitmap sprite;
    private int x, y, speed;

    //Animation Variables
    private static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 4;
    private static final int SPRITE_COLUMNS = 4;
    private int currentFrame, width, height, srcY, srcX, direction;
    Rect src, dst;

    //Static Directions
    private static int DIRECTION_STATIONARY = 0;
    private static int DIRECTION_DOWN = 1;
    private static int DIRECTION_LEFT = 2;
    private static int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 3;
    private static int DIRECTION_UP = 4;

    GameView gameView;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public Player (Context context, GameView gameView){
        this.gameView = gameView;

        mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        x = 100;
        y = 500;

        speed = 30;

        sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.player);

        width = sprite.getWidth() / SPRITE_COLUMNS;
        height = sprite.getHeight() / SPRITE_ROWS;
    }

    public void Update() {

        Log.d("Player | Update", "" + direction);
        if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_UP){
            y -= speed;
            direction = DIRECTION_UP;
        }

        else if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_DOWN){
            y += speed;
            direction = DIRECTION_DOWN;
        }
        else if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_RIGHT){
            x += speed;
            direction = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_LEFT){
            x -= speed;
            direction = DIRECTION_LEFT;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAnim(){

        currentFrame = ++currentFrame % SPRITE_COLUMNS;
        srcX = currentFrame * width;

        if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_RIGHT){
            srcY = 2 * height;
        }
        else if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_LEFT){
            srcY = 1 * height;
        }
        if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_DOWN){

            srcY = 0 * height;
        }
        else if (mainActivity.getDirection() == DIRECTION_UP){
            srcY = 3 * height;
        }

        src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
        dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    public Rect getSrc(){
        return src;
    }

    public Rect getDst(){
        return dst;
    }

    public Bitmap getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shorten the code to a [mcve], and point us to where you set the `int` value and where you are trying to pass and receive it?

Comment: Without knowing what the values in `sensorEvent.values[0]` and `sensorEvent.values[1]` are it is very hard to tell. Can you tell us what `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)` is receiving as a parameter?

Comment: @Pieter sensorEvent.values[0-2] are generated by the accelorometer and they work fine, [0] is x, [1] is y and [2] is z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mainActivity = new MainActivity();

Here you are creating a new instance of your MainActivity.
This instance does not have the direction information that you want.

This is not how you pass information from Activities in Android. What you can probably do is create an object of Player in your MainActivity and set direction of Player in MainActivity.

```
Player player = new Player();
```

And in `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)` method in MainActivity -

```
player.setDirection(direction);
player.update();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you! Only problem is I cant add the player class like you have said as if I add it in the onCreate I get errors as it doesnt contain gameView and context however I cant seem to add Context to the onCreate method? Do you konw how I can add the player class to the main activity?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'Cant seem to add Context to the onCreate method'. You can get the context in any function in an Activity by using getApplicationContext. Add this line to your onCreate method -  `player = new Player(getApplicationContext(), gameView);`